# Why does the ToSimplifyText remain unchanged?

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a program which would remove the 4000 most used words from some text you put in using a prompt. This I did with a loop which removes words you find on the list one by one until the index reaches the end of the list and you have removed all 4000 (see code below). The problem is that nothing gets removed and my output is the same as input. My input is the text "The Chungus" and "The" is the first word on the list.

I have checked if every function and datatype is correct, and indeed if I remove the loop and substitute numbers for the CurrentSpaceIndex and CurrentWordStart, then the output is correct: "Chungus".

```
var x = "The be and of a in to have to ... "; //It's a list of the 4000 most used words in english. 4000 words with a space between them. The length of the string is 29307 characters, so the last character will have index 29306..

var ToSimplifyText = prompt("Please enter the text you wish to simplify:", "");

var WordToRemove;

var CurrentSpaceIndex = 0;

var CurrentWordStart = 0;

var CurrentChar;


while(CurrentSpaceIndex < 29307){
    CurrentChar = x.charAt(CurrentSpaceIndex);
    if (CurrentChar = " "){
    WordToRemove = x.substring(CurrentWordStart, CurrentSpaceIndex);
    ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(WordToRemove, "");
    CurrentWordStart = CurrentSpaceIndex + 1;
    }
    CurrentSpaceIndex = CurrentSpaceIndex + 1;
}
alert(ToSimplifyText);
```

I expect the output to be `Chungus`instead of the unchanged `The Chungus`.

Comment: on an unrelated note, I would recommend using `camelCase` for variable names (first letter is lowercase, the next words; uppercase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it very hard way. You can do it in following steps:

- Convert both strings to array of words using `split()`
- Then `filter()` the words from the user input which is present in words array.
- At last use `join()` and return the result.

```js
var x = "The be and of a in to have to"; //It's a list of the 4000 most used words in english. 4000 words with a space between them. The length of the string is 29307 characters, so the last character will have index 29306..
var ToSimplifyText = prompt("Please enter the text you wish to simplify:", "");

const removeWords = (str,words) => str.split(' ').filter(x => !words.includes(x)).join(' ');

ToSimplifyText = removeWords(ToSimplifyText,x.split(' '))

alert(ToSimplifyText);
```

#### Why Your code doesnot work?

The reason is the use of Assigment Operator instead of comparison operator.

```
if (CurrentChar = " ")
```

should be

```
if (CurrentChar === " ")
```

```js
var x = "The be and of a in to have to"; //It's a list of the 4000 most used words in english. 4000 words with a space between them. The length of the string is 29307 characters, so the last character will have index 29306..

var ToSimplifyText = prompt("Please enter the text you wish to simplify:", "");

var WordToRemove;

var CurrentSpaceIndex = 0;

var CurrentWordStart = 0;

var CurrentChar;


while(CurrentSpaceIndex < x.length){
    CurrentChar = x.charAt(CurrentSpaceIndex);
    if (CurrentChar === " "){
    WordToRemove = x.substring(CurrentWordStart, CurrentSpaceIndex);
    console.log(WordToRemove)
    ToSimplifyText = ToSimplifyText.replace(WordToRemove, "");
    CurrentWordStart = CurrentSpaceIndex + 1;
    }
    CurrentSpaceIndex = CurrentSpaceIndex + 1;
}
alert(ToSimplifyText);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea functions like these existed, this is indeed simpler. Why is it that my code didn't work? It is indeed hard but it should have worked, right?

Comment: @DaddyMike I have added an explanation why ur function doesnot work.See the updated post